# In my Android App Actionbar is visible in View of Android Studio but on installing the app on Phone it is not visible why?

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar

Also when i remove theme from manifest file Actionbar is visible on phone with some random theme.
I tried using other themes too but those are not working in giving me Actionbar.
I removed style file and tried to give theme in manifest file too but this didn't worked too.
My parent Theme is DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar and Android Studio version is 1.1.0.
Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionBarActivity javadoc:
Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), the action bar appears at the top of an activity's window when the activity uses the system's Holo theme (or one of its descendant themes), which is the default. You may otherwise add the action bar by calling requestFeature(FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) or by declaring it in a custom theme with the windowActionBar property.
anyway, you have to use Holo theme if you are using API 11 or uper.
however, you can use AppCompat library. and set your theme ase: @style/Theme.AppCompat (or one of its descendant themes)

Comment: Sorry to say none of this worked for me..
On calling requestFeature(FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) it is comming cannot resolve this method.

Comment: ok, maybe. note that DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar is not compatible with android ActionBar. 
you have to use android holo theme: @android:style/Theme.Holo
or 
ActionBar AppCompat theme: @style/Theme.AppCompat if you are using android AppCompat with ActionBarActivity.

Comment: I am new to android so i am not sure, on changing this it is giving 'files under built folder are generated and should not be edited'.

Comment: ok, if you are new to android, i recomand you to use Holo theme with android 3.0 or uper.
in your Manifest File. ensure you to put this:
<uses-sdk
 android:minSdkVersion="11"
 android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
 
 <application
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
  
  android:minSdkVersion="11" indicate that you use android 3.0 or uper
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" indicate that you use Holo theme which are actionBar compatible.
  please try this on your MANIFEST.